# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "post[date]" that is not disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I am getting errors while doing integration tests with rspec and the problem here lies with the `fill_in` , can anyone explain me why this is happening??

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'navigate' do

  describe "index" do
    before do
      @user = User.create(email:"test@test.com", password:"test123", password_confirmation:"test123", first_name:"Umair", last_name:"Ahmed")
      
    end

    it "can be reached successfully" do
        visit posts_path
        expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)      
    end

  end

  describe "new and create" do
    before do
      user = User.create(email:"test@test.com", password:"test123", password_confirmation:"test123", first_name:"Umair", last_name:"Ahmed")
      login_as(user, scope: user)
      visit new_post_path
    end

    it "has a new form" do
      expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)
    end

    it "will fill in details of form" do
      fill_in "post[date]", with: Date.today
      fill_in "post[rationale]",    with: "something rationale"  

      click_on "Save"

      expect(page).to have_content("something rationale") 
    end

    it "will have a user associated with it" do
      fill_in "post[date]", with: Date.today
      fill_in "post[rationale]",    with: "User Association"  

      click_on "Save"
      expect(User.first.posts.first.rationale).to eq("User Association")  
      
    end
    
    
  end
  
  
end
```

post.rb (model)

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
    validates_presence_of :date, :rationale
end
```

views/posts/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.date_field :date %>
    <%= f.text_area :rationale %>

    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

I can't seem to understand what is wrong here, can anyone point out what rubbish I am doing here?

Comment: What error are you seeing? Please edit your question to include it in full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I fixed the issue by just changing `login_as(user, scope: user)` to
`login_as(user, scope: :user)` , or we can type like this if you like this type of syntax
`login_as(user, :scope => :user)`

Comment: what version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Oh, it's not a Ruby version problem, but a typo. `scope: user` us equivalent to `:scope => user`. You want to write `scope: :user`

Comment: oh yeah,i noticed dat and i forgot to update the answer, anywyas thanks :D